# How do I know if my Arduino is connected to my LEDs?

Tags: led

I have an Arduino Uno and a string of WS2811 LEDs. I am still trying to get started on this project, which is creating [a Stranger Things wall](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Stranger-Things-Lights/). I've installed FastLED and uploaded the sample program "Blink" to the Arduino, which appears to upload correctly. However, the lights don't blink.

Notes:
 - When I plug the string of lights into a power source (when disconnected from the Arduino), they briefly light up red and then turn off. I don't know if this means there's something wrong with the power setup. (I don't know if they are supposed to stay on.)
 - Here's a photo of my connection from the Arduino to the LEDs
 [image]

- Here's the setup I'm trying to follow.
  [image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The FastLed Blink sketch uses pin 3 as the data pin. Did you change that to 6?

Comment: THANK YOU. These noob roadblocks can be so silly. I'm off and running now!

Comment: Great. Just in time for Halloween. Make sure you don't plug it in "upside down" q-;

Comment: Haha - I'll be careful :)

Comment: i was going to say; a flash and red is a good sign, sounds like the pin config is just off...

Answer (score 2):

The sample code sets the data pin to 3, but I was using 6. Noob mistake.